# How to change percent type in proc freq (SAS)

Tags: sas, frequency

I'm computing conditional frequency of two variables in a dataset with this:

```
proc freq data=input noprint;
tables VAR1 * VAR2 / out=output; 
run;
```

I want to know if for every `VAR1-i` there are more than one type of `VAR2-i`. But in the output there is `count` that count how many times `VAR2-i` is present for `VAR-1-i` (as I want) while `percent` is the percent of `count` on the total number of records of the `dataset` instead I want the percent on the total of records of `VAR1-i`.

How can I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the outpct option.

```
proc freq data=input noprint;
   tables VAR1 * VAR2 / out=output outpct; 
run;
```